# Probability of 4-number matching in a lottery in two different situations?

Tags: probability

In some lottery, 7 numbers are drawn and each of them from numbers ${\{1, \dots, 45}\}$. To win "Division 6" means to have 4 of 7 drawn numbers. The order of drawn numbers doesn't matter.

My questions are:

1- Probability of winning "Division 6" (= 4 winning numbers) is 1:154. How this ratio is calculated? Meaning, I have bought a ticket of 7 numbers, and 7 numbers drawn are $a_1, \dots, a_7$ respectively; what is the probability that any 4 numbers out of 7 numbers in my ticket be same as any 4 numbers out of $a_1 \dots, a_7$?

2- What is probability of having four numbers of drawn numbers in the first 4 draws out of 7 draws? Meaning, I have bought a ticket of 7 numbers, and 7 numbers drawn are $a_1, \dots, a_7$ respectively; what is the probability that any 4 numbers out of 7 numbers in my ticket be same as $a_1 \dots, a_4$? Actually, this second question is a generalization problem and is not in real lottery.

Detailed answers would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are numbers drawn unique? (Are they drawn from a pool of the numbers $1$ through $45$, where there is one of each number, without replacement?)

Comment: Use the hypergeometic distribution

Comment: @LuckyGuy: See my edited comment.

Comment: @DivergentQueries No replacement. when e.g. 6 is drawn, there is no other 6 to be drawn.

Comment: @Peter: I only know how to calculate matching all 7 numbers: (7!*38!/45!)=1/45379620.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of possible combinations is $$\binom{45}{7}$$

The number of combinations with exactly $4$ hits is

$$\binom {7}{4}\times\binom {38}{3}$$

This solves problem Nr. $1$

The probabilitiy is $0.006506444963620233047345923126$ , which is about $\frac{1}{154}$

For problem $2$, the solution is :

$$\frac {\binom {7}{4}}{\binom {45}{4}}=\frac{1}{4257}=0.0002349072116513976979093258163$$

Comment: I can understand $\binom {7}{4}$ and $\times$, but where $\binom {38}{3}$ comes from? Well obviously I know $3=7-4$ and $38=45-7$.

Comment: @LuckyGuy: This is the case where you choose *exactly* $4$ successful numbers, so you choose the remaining $3$ from the collection of $38$ "failing" numbers.

Comment: tn R software: `dhyper(4, 7, 45 - 7, 7)` returns ` 0.006506445`. First argument is number 'red' sought, second is number 'red', in urn, third is number 'white' in urn, fourth is, number drawn without replacement. Look at hypergeometric density function if it's in your text.

Comment: I am not quite sure about problem $2$. Do I understand right, that you want to have the probability that the first $4$ drawn numbers in lottery are in your chosen combination ?

Comment: Pretend only 4 are drawn. 0.0002349072

Comment: @Peter: exactly! the **the first** 4 numbers of drawn numbers be among 7 numbers of my ticket.

Comment: well, that was easy! Now you can just print a screen shot of the edited answer and turn that in.

Comment: @Peter: Thank you very much for your answer since it can help me to have some guidance. However, I have to study some basics to understand your answer (still by Divergent Queries' comment I couldn't understand completely).

Comment: Keep asking if something is still unclear.

Comment: Actually now I could understand completely the first answer, but sorry not the second answer at all! Why **division** and why $\binom {45}{4}$ and if division why over $\binom {7}{4}$? Thank you.

Comment: OK, there are $\binom {45}{4}$ possibilities to draw $4$ numbers out of $45$. And there are $\binom {7}{4}$ possibilities to get $4$ out of the $7$ drawn numbers. Since we have the Laplacian case (each combination has the same probability), just divide the two numbers.

Comment: Would you please explain "Laplacian case (each combination has the same probability)" or if it requires a lot of knowledge to explain please let me know some link so I can learn it? I still didn't get reason for division. Thank you

Comment: In the Laplacian case, you have, lets say, $n$ so-called elementary-events and for each of them the probability that it occurs is $\frac{1}{n}$. If some event contains $m$ elementary events, where $m\le n$, the probability that it occurs is $m\times \frac{1}{n}=\frac{m}{n}$ because different elementary events cannot occur simultaneosly (in this case the probabilities sum up). So, in the Laplacian case, you only need to count the total number of possibilities and the number of events leading to the given event.